# appending variable to an input value using val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code appends `text goes here` to an input value

```
$('#someid').val($('#someid').val() + 'text goes here');
```

I'm trying to use variable like below but It isn't working

```
var someText= text goes here;
$('#someid').val($('#someid').val() + 'someText');
```

How can I properly append variable using val() ?

Comment: element which holding id someid is an text box?

Comment: if it is normal html element you have to use append()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take away the quotes so you're accessing the variable and not the string literal.

```
var someText = 'foo bar';
$('#someid').val($('#someid').val() + someText);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't use string delimiters around a variable:

```
$('#someid').val($('#someid').val() + someText);
```

Answer (score 2):

assign your variable like a string; below

```
var someText= "text goes here";
$('#someid').val($('#someid').val() + someText);
```

Comment: you still have the `'someText'` variable in quotes

Comment: Never a problem, i'm glad to help it was just a simple typo/mistake anyways.  Just want to make sure that the answer is correct, because it's important that users get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg87b90s/)

**Description**

In my jQuery you'll see that I used `.html` this can easily be switched to `.val` if needed.  I used `.html` only for demo's sake, the main part to learn is that a variable is used by name only.

**HTML**

```
<p id='someid'>more stuff</p>
```

**JS**

```
# someText is a string variable by putting quotes around the text
var someText=' text goes here';
# someText is a variable and thus is just appended without quotes
$('#someid').html($('#someid').html() + someText);
```